# I need to calculate the value of some checked radio buttons using DOM

Tags: javascript, html

My code so far is:
HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="age" value="0">1-25
<input type="radio" name="age" value="5">26-27
<input type="radio" name="age" value="7">28-29

<input type="radio" name="bmi" value="0">0-25
<input type="radio" name="bmi" value="0">26-30
<input type="radio" name="bmi" value="9">31-35
```

So I need to get the value of the checked radio buttons and calculate them

Javascript as the first answer that I've got

```
function CalculateValue(){
  //call getAgeValue(), getBmiValue() here and do desired calculations here
}

function getAgeValue()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName('age').length; i++)
    {
        if (document.getElementsByName('age')[i].checked)
        {
            return document.getElementsByName('age')[i].value;
        }
    }
}

function getBmiValue()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName('bmi').length; i++)
    {
        if (document.getElementsByName('bmi')[i].checked)
        {
            return document.getElementsByName('bmi')[i].value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using jquery or just plain vanilla javascript?

Comment: I don't understand what the radio buttons' values mean. Why is the age value "5" at 26-27 and "7" at 28-29? Why are BMI values 0 for both 0-25 and 26-30? What should the calculate button calculate anyway?

Comment: hello. i need to calculate the diabetes risk and the values are being given to me. so, if you're older, the value incresease. let's say that age value will be 5 and bmi value will be 9. that means that the diabetes risk is medium risk because the value is between 10 and 14. they are the same because the risk for bmi 0-25 and 26-30 = 0;

Answer (score 2):

Making use of the vanilla [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector)

```
function doCalculation(ageValue, bmiValue) {
    // whatever
    return ageValue + bmiValue;
}

function getRadioValue(radio_name) {
    return ( // parenthesis to let us do an OR
      document.querySelector('input[type="radio"][name="' + radio_name + '"]:checked')
      || // or if none is checked
      {} // so we don't get an error
    ).value;
}

function handlerForButton(e) {
    var age = +getRadioValue('age'),
        bmi = +getRadioValue('bmi'),
        foo = doCalculation(age, bmi);
    // do whateverwith foo
    console.log(foo);
}

// after elements exist
document.querySelector('input[type="button"][value="Calculate"]')
    .addEventListener('click', handlerForButton);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/p3F3r/)

You may find it easier to use *classes* and *ids* to find your elements rather than seeking them out using their other attributes. This would also improve performance

Comment: I need to do it using DOM. I can't use document.querySelector. This is a project for a course that I'm doing and I'm supposed to only do with what we have learned so far.